# How to fill a rectangular area with non-intersecting rotated rectangles?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, 2d

I try to create a scene for physical simulation. The scene consists of rectangular floes floating in a rectangular pond. Something like this:

[image: Rectangular floes]

So I need to fill a rectangular area with non-intersecting rotated rectangles with widths and heights in a specified range. I don't need to find an optimal coverage of the area. The goal is just to generate floes of different size without intersections.

And I'd like to get a solution without any dynamics, only using collision detection algorithms.

Comment: Sure it can't be optimal ---- the optimal solution will be tiles.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is what I would do:

Suppose the length of the rectangles are between [MaxSize MinSize]

```
r <- MaxSize

do{
  Trying adding non-intersecting circles to the area with radius r and random center (x,y). We use circle instead of rectangle because intersection detecting for circles are easier than rectangles. e.g. if distance(x,y,x',y')<r+r' then we are good.

  If adding circle failed{
    r--;
    if r< MinSize break;
  }
}
```

Now you will have a plane full of on intersecting squares. There will be gaps because we were using circles as intersection detection. If this is not good enough for you, grow the squares to rectangles. You can do this by checking all points against a certain border and decide how much you can grow it.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider simulating a collection of boxes falling into a square bucket and saving the positions of all the boxes once they come to rest.

[`box2d`](http://box2d.org) is an open source 2D physics library that can do this for you - you might recognise it as the physics engine behind Angry Birds and umpteen-million Flash games.

Comment: not bad idea, but I'd like to get a solution without any dynamics, only using collision detection. I've updated my question according to this comment.

Answer (score 1):

To model solid (ie non-intersecting) objects, you could use a **physics engine**. As it happens I just the other day read [Farseer tutorial for the absolute beginners](http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2012/04/13/farseer-tutorial-for-the-absolute-beginners.aspx), which includes a video depicting almost exactly your requirement. [Farseer](http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/) is a .NET version of box2d, which you may have heard of.